# php framework, data works in var_dump but not in echo

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am so confused right now, I am using code igniter php framework and have passed an array to the view so I can access the variable from within the view.

So in this view when I do

```
echo var_dump($data["mykey"]);
```

I get

```
string '43' (length=2)
```

but when I try

```
echo $data["mykey"];
```

I get

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: "mykey"
Line Number: 8
```

???

EDIT (problem seems to be when code igniter tries to return from the view to pass it back to the controller as a string, this is my conclusion because if I put a die at the end of the view it works)

The `$data` array is like so and in my view I try to do `echo $data["myfield"][0]["data"]`

```
array
  'myfield' => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'data' => string '1'
  'myfieldb' => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'data' => string '2'
```

Comment: You don't need to echo a `var_dump` - try just `var_dump($data);` and post what shows.

Comment: try maybe replacing double quotes by simple quotes in your echo command.

Comment: thanks, so I did some more test and if I do a die after the echo it works but if I let code igniter return from the view processing, I get the error so I think its a problem with the framework

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you change the name of $data to something else, even, say, $data_vars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I recreate what you've given in PHP

```
<?php

    $array = array(
              'myfield' => 
                array(
                  0 => 
                    array(
                      'data' => '1')),
              'myfieldb' => 
                array(
                  0 => 
                    array(
                      'data' => '2')));

    echo $array['myfield'][0]['data'];

?>
```

It echo's fine.

That error you're getting means that the key specified doesn't exist.  I would do a `print_r($data)` and see what you get.

Answer (score 3):

in your controller

```
class controller extends CI_Controller {

function hello() {
  $data['world'] = 'world';
  $this->load->view('test');
 }
}
```

in your view

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
Hello <?php echo $world ?>;
</body>
</html>
```

Array keys passed to views are converted to variables.

So to access `$data['mykey']` in your view you must access it like `$mykey` instead of `$data['mykey']`.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
Your key is: <?php echo $mykey ?>;
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the [user_guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)